# Charles proxy certificate, import button unactive

Tags: certificates, 23.04

I have encountered a problem with importing the Charles proxy certificate into the system. When trying to do it from the GUI, the 'Import' button is greyed out, and it displays the message 'Cannot import because there are no compatible importers'.
I also tried manually placing the certificate and using 'update-ca-certificate', but it didn't work either.

Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Have you checked that the certificate is in PEM format (not DER/binary)? I would follow the Ubuntu documentation and use the command-line to import the certificate https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store

Comment: @Robert I checked, Charles proxy itself trying to import .cer format. Though it has an alternative, to save the certificate in .pem format as I know Ubuntu should support and import it or manually. But PEM certificate with GUI gives the same result as CER from the program, inactive Import button. And importing PEM by command-line didn't give me the result too. Maybe I follow wrong instruction in CLI...